# ReactJS and Twilio - TypeError: this.props.history not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio-programmable-chat

Learning React for the first time, and opted to use Twilio's chat app demo to get a jump start.

I can render the welcome screen without issue, but not routed to the chat screen/room when I login. Including link to demo, code snippets, notes and more below.

Anyone out there see what's going on here and can advise? I've fixed a few issues so far that came up due to updates since the demo was posted (change `Switch` to `Routes`, etc.), but haven't been able to get past this `TypeError`. Any and all help is welcome and TIA!

Link to Twilio Demo: [Twilio Programmable Chat App Demo](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-a-chat-app-with-twilio-programmable-chat-and-react)

The error is raised in the login() function, at the line: `this.props.history.push('chat', { email, room });` and the error reads `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.history is undefined` .

As an aside, I have attempted to import the `withRouter` method from `react-router-dom` but the method is not exported from `react-router-dom` and all information I am finding online about this method points to an older version of `react-router-dom` than what I am working with, so this is not a workable solution. I've also tried to apply `.bind(this)` on the `onClick` that calls `login()`, but this did not work either.

**WelcomeScreen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Grid,
  TextField,
  Card,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  Button,
 } from "@material-ui/core";


class WelcomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        email: "",
        room: "",
    };
}

login = () => {
    const { room, email } = this.state;
    if (room && email) {
        this.props.history.push("chat", { room, email });
    }
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
};

render() {
    const { email, room } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <AppBar style={styles.header} elevation={10}>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6">
              Chat App with Twilio Programmable Chat and React
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Grid
          style={styles.grid}
          container
          direction="column"
          justify="center"
          alignItems="center">
          <Card style={styles.card} elevation={10}>
            <Grid item style={styles.gridItem}>
              <TextField
                name="email"
                required
                style={styles.textField}
                label="Email address"
                placeholder="Enter email address"
                variant="outlined"
                type="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item style={styles.gridItem}>
              <TextField
                name="room"
                required
                style={styles.textField}
                label="Room"
                placeholder="Enter room name"
                variant="outlined"
                value={room}
                onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item style={styles.gridItem}>
              <Button
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
                style={styles.button}
                onClick={this.login}>
                Login
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </>
    );
  }      
}

const styles = {
  header: {},
  grid: { position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
  card: { padding: 40 },
  textField: { width: 300 },
  gridItem: { paddingTop: 12, paddingBottom: 12 },
  button: { width: 300 },
};  

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

**ChatScreen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  AppBar,
  Backdrop,
  CircularProgress,
  Container,
  CssBaseline,
  Grid,
  IconButton,
  List,
  TextField,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Send } from "@material-ui/icons";
import axios from "axios";
import ChatItem from "./ChatItem";
const Chat = require("twilio-chat");


 class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        text: "",
        messages: [],
        loading: false,
        channel: null,
    };

    this.scrollDiv = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount = async () => {
    const { location } = this.props;
    const { state } = location || {};
    const { email, room } = state || {};
    let token = "";
  
    if (!email || !room) {
        this.props.history.replace("/");
    }
  
    this.setState({ loading: true });
  
    try {
        token = await this.getToken(email);
    } catch {
        throw new Error("Unable to get token, please reload this page");
    }

    const client = await Chat.Client.create(token);

    client.on("tokenAboutToExpire", async () => {
        const token = await this.getToken(email);
        client.updateToken(token);
    });

    client.on("tokenExpired", async () => {
        const token = await this.getToken(email);
        client.updateToken(token);
    });

    client.on("channelJoined", async (channel) => {
        // getting list of all messages since this is an existing channel
        const messages = await channel.getMessages();
        this.setState({ messages: messages.items || [] });
        this.scrollToBottom();
    });
    
    try {
        const channel = await client.getChannelByUniqueName(room);
        this.joinChannel(channel);
    } catch(err) {
        try {
            const channel = await client.createChannel({
                uniqueName: room,
                friendlyName: room,
        });
      
            this.joinChannel(channel);
        } catch {
            throw new Error("Unable to create channel, please reload this page");
        }
    }
}
  
getToken = async (email) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/token/${email}`);
    const { data } = response;
    return data.token;
}

joinChannel = async (channel) => {
    if (channel.channelState.status !== "joined") {
        await channel.join();
   }
 
    this.setState({ 
        channel:channel, 
        loading: false 
    });
 
   channel.on("messageAdded", this.handleMessageAdded);
   this.scrollToBottom();
};
 
 
handleMessageAdded = (message) => {
    const { messages } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        messages: [...messages, message],
    },
        this.scrollToBottom
    );
};
 
scrollToBottom = () => {
    const scrollHeight = this.scrollDiv.current.scrollHeight;
    const height = this.scrollDiv.current.clientHeight;
    const maxScrollTop = scrollHeight - height;
    this.scrollDiv.current.scrollTop = maxScrollTop > 0 ? maxScrollTop : 0;
};

sendMessage = () => {
    const { text, channel } = this.state;
    if (text) {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        channel.sendMessage(String(text).trim());
        this.setState({ text: "", loading: false });
    }
};

render() {
    const { loading, text, messages, channel } = this.state;
    const { location } = this.props;
    const { state } = location || {};
    const { email, room } = state || {};
  
    return (
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="md">
        <Backdrop open={loading} style={{ zIndex: 99999 }}>
          <CircularProgress style={{ color: "white" }} />
        </Backdrop>
  
        <AppBar elevation={10}>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6">
              {`Room: ${room}, User: ${email}`}
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
  
        <CssBaseline />
  
        <Grid container direction="column" style={styles.mainGrid}>
          <Grid item style={styles.gridItemChatList} ref={this.scrollDiv}>
            <List dense={true}>
                {messages &&
                  messages.map((message) => 
                    <ChatItem
                      key={message.index}
                      message={message}
                      email={email}/>
                  )}
            </List>
          </Grid>
  
          <Grid item style={styles.gridItemMessage}>
            <Grid
              container
              direction="row"
              justify="center"
              alignItems="center">
              <Grid item style={styles.textFieldContainer}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  style={styles.textField}
                  placeholder="Enter message"
                  variant="outlined"
                  multiline
                  rows={2}
                  value={text}
                  disabled={!channel}
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    this.setState({ text: event.target.value })
                  }/>
              </Grid>
              
              <Grid item>
                <IconButton
                  style={styles.sendButton}
                  onClick={this.sendMessage}
                  disabled={!channel}>
                  <Send style={styles.sendIcon} />
                </IconButton>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    );
  }      
}

const styles = {
    textField: { width: "100%", borderWidth: 0, borderColor: "transparent" },
    textFieldContainer: { flex: 1, marginRight: 12 },
    gridItem: { paddingTop: 12, paddingBottom: 12 },
    gridItemChatList: { overflow: "auto", height: "70vh" },
    gridItemMessage: { marginTop: 12, marginBottom: 12 },
    sendButton: { backgroundColor: "#3f51b5" },
    sendIcon: { color: "white" },
    mainGrid: { paddingTop: 100, borderWidth: 1 },
};

export default ChatScreen;
```

**Router.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, } from "react-router-dom";
import WelcomeScreen from "./WelcomeScreen";
import ChatScreen from "./ChatScreen";

function Router() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/chat" element={<ChatScreen/>} />
        <Route path="/" element={<WelcomeScreen/>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

Comment: If `ChatScreen` and `WindowScreen` are **functional Components**, then you can use `useNavigate` instead of `useHistory`. But can't find anything specific for **class component**

Comment: This is basically because, `element` in `<Route/>` do not pass any history prop.

Answer (score 0):

If `ChatScreen` and `WindowScreen` are **functional Components**, then you can directly use `useNavigate` instead of `useHistory`.
**But can't find anything specific for class component.**
It is given in migration from v5 section of the documentation.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

You can search for `useNavigate`.

---

### Solution (*workaround*)

> You can create a **Function** `Wrapper Component` around your class
> components and in that component, you can pass props like
>
> - `navigate from useNavigate`

I have taken an idea from `HOC components` in react.
Here is an example of what I tried and have worked.
https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-moon-30br5?file=/src/Comp.js

This can work till we don't find a legitimate method of doing the same.

> you can click on Click button in route `/1` and it successfully navigates to route `/2`

***Note:** See the console for the passed props in the **Sandox's console***

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In your `Router.js` file you have:

```
        <Route path="/chat" element={<ChatScreen/>} />
        <Route path="/" element={<WelcomeScreen/>} />
```

The correct attribute is [`component`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) not `element`. So your `Router.js` should look like this:

```
        <Route path="/chat" component={<ChatScreen/>} />
        <Route path="/"     component={<WelcomeScreen/>} />
```

Comment: this is incorrect. element is used for react-router-dom v6 in place of component. Switch was also replaced with Routes. per my earlier note, no issue rendering the welcome screen, so that is not at issue and would also not throw the error related to props.

Comment: Ah, didn’t realise you were following the tutorial but also updating React Router. Looks like history is no longer passed through the props. You could try updating `this.props.location.pathname` instead. Or change to a functional component and use the `navigate` function returned from the ‘useNavigate` hook.

Comment: My bad, probably should've mentioned that in that case. Gonna play around more with this and circle back if anything but thanks for your attention to this. it is greatly appreciated.